# I got complition error _GLIBCXX_PERMIT_BACKWARD_HASH on android NDK when using hash_map

Tags: android, c++, hashmap, cocos2d-x, android-stlport

I'm in progress of porting my cocos2d-x project from win32 to android. I've been using the hash_map and it causes a lot of problems now.

I googled that I need to include it from different sources on Android NDK and win32, like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <ext/hash_map>
#else
#include <hash_map>
#endif
```

but still, when I compile on NDK r7b I got compilation error:

> D:/Developer/Android/android-ndk-r7b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/ext/hash_map:60:30: error: backward_warning.h: No such file or directory

It fails on including backward_warning.h file

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_PERMIT_BACKWARD_HASH
#include "backward_warning.h"
#endif
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Consider using [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/libs/unordered/) instead of the compiler-supplied implementation.

Comment: @ildjarn will it compile on android NDK and later on the iphone XCode3/4?

Comment: Yes to both. Also note that the implementation is header-only, so no separate compilation or linking is required -- just include the necessary headers and you're good to go.

Comment: Note that this was fixed upstream in Android NDK Revision 9.

Answer (score 4):

add a macro in Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    :=  -D_GLIBCXX_PERMIT_BACKWARD_HASH
```

Comment: For those building Android apps using Qt Creator, just add the flag as a define to the relevant .pro file(s) restricted to the android-g++ scope.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a delayed answer, but here is a solution for others that have this problem.  You just need to fix the path. Edit your gnu-libstdc++/include/ext/hash_map file and make the following change.  It will correctly display the build warning now instead of exiting with missing file error.

Change:

```
#include "backward_warning.h"
```

To:

```
#include "../backward/backward_warning.h"
```

Comment: But then you get a deprecated error. Unordered_map should be used instead, but I don't know how to include it.

Answer (score 0):

The local solution is to `#include <backward/hash_map>` instead of  `#include <ext/hash_map>`

I've just bugged this with Google as [Issue 53404](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53404) and the best solution I can see involves editing your NDK:

Edit `sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk`, find the line `gnustl_exported_c_includes` and add:

```
$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)/include/backward
```

That makes the include paths used by the NDK match those used by g++ in its normal configuration.

Edit: Google have applied this fix upstream; the fix was released with "Android NDK, Revision 9" in July 2013.